# BrowserSync не отслеживает изменения

Tags: javascript, gulp, twig

Проблема с browserSync не отслеживает изменения в файлах. Проблема замечена на ОС Windows на OSX все работает нормально.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');
const reload = browserSync.reload;
const twig = require('gulp-twig');

const PATHS = {
  src: 'src/',
  dist: 'dist/'
};

gulp.task('views',() =>
  gulp.src(PATHS.src + 'views/*.twig')
    .pipe(twig())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/views'))
);
gulp.task('serve', ['views'], () => {
  browserSync({
    notify: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: [PATHS.dist + 'views', PATHS.dist]
    }
});

gulp.watch([PATHS.src +'views/**/*.twig'], ['views']).on('change', reload);
```

При изменении фалов *.twig таск views не вызывается

Comment: В таске views `gulp.src(PATHS.src + 'views/*.twig')` работает с файлами только из папки views, а `gulp.watch([PATHS.src +'views/**/*.twig'], ['views'])` смотрит файлы в папке views и в под папках, может быть здесь ошибка и надо сделать `gulp.src(PATHS.src + 'views/**/.*.twig')` в таксе views.

Comment: @stackanon, дело в том что если запустить команду gulp serve и открыть второе окно терминала и запускать там команду gulp views то он отслеживает это изменение и перезагружает сервер и в первом окне терминала говорится что все скомпилировалось. а при изменение файлов он не хочет запускать task views

Comment: Попробуйте https://jsfiddle.net/4p82otjd/ запускается gulp watch